# Searching for a potential to determine conservation in a vector field.

Tags: vector-fields

I have a vector field
$$
F = xe^{xy}(xy+1),ye^{xy}(xy+1)
$$

and i am trying to show that it is conservative with a potential.
$$
\frac{d\Phi}{dx} = xe^{xy}(xy+1) ,   \frac{d\Phi}{dy} = ye^{xy}(xy+1)
$$
$$
\Phi(x,y) = e^{xy}(x^2-\frac{x}{y}+\frac{1}{y^2})+g(y)
$$

After this i try to differentiate this with respect of y but i cant really solve it. When i,m trying to use wolfram alpha it says that it cannot be solved with standard mathematical functions. How would i continue from here to know if this vector field is conservative?

Comment: Did you check that $\partial_y F_x=\partial_x F_y$ ? This is a necessary condition for the field to be conservative.

Comment: Yes this is true, and as @SolubleFish mentions we should continue to look at the problem, we should find a potential to this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a conservative vector field. For a two dimensional vector field, $\vec F = (P, Q) \ $ to be conservative, we must have

$\displaystyle \frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial P}{\partial y}$

$\displaystyle \vec F = \big(xe^{xy}(xy+1),ye^{xy}(xy+1)\big)$

$P = xe^{xy}(xy+1), Q = ye^{xy}(xy+1)$

$\displaystyle \frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} = y^2 e^{xy} (xy + 2), \  \frac{\partial P}{\partial y} = x^2 e^{xy} (xy + 2)$

$\displaystyle \frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} \ne \frac{\partial P}{\partial y}$

Comment: Please note that if $P$ and $Q$ components of vector field were switched, it would then be a conservative vector field with potential function of $xy e^{xy}$.